# Difference in JS and python encrypted string

Tags: python, node.js, encryption

I am trying to make my python function work the same as my js function and I can not figure out the difference between these two pieces of code.  I have a feeling something is different with python's int() and node's forge.jsbn.BigInteger.  Could anyone spot the difference between these two code samples?

Python (not working)

```
import base64
import hashlib

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

def returnSignature():
    password = "6b0d"
    salt = "1234"
    mod = "18482445774037006176143036388197818377224243341874299759393986316969168081293431967665057665354002144386679806241726680717167432197115393709044305367801562368377199313542622242088334493968227031303600659164182705200363370843349892071172286671217348220799611979367426886573857836700695154474387375045676161964264719840020610569587332497543980147743876907161648026576356758480646523434992364261325929823041766729482733300160147897964050534385377467240755626731087578114754411412866113305365456719741211653254865891742861999731525476635260033457850071277557432915055294927970289560714643822194080384022366782758886009197"
    exp = "65537"

    sha_1 = hashlib.sha1()
    sha_1.update(password.encode())

    password_sha1 = sha_1.hexdigest()
    salted_password = password_sha1 + salt
    SHA3_512_password_salted = hashlib.sha3_512(bytes.fromhex(salted_password)).digest()

    n = int(mod, 10)
    e = int(exp, 10)

    RSA_key = RSA.construct((n, e))
    publicKey = RSA_key.public_key()

    encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(publicKey)
    encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(SHA3_512_password_salted)

    final = encrypted.hex()
    
    return final

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(returnSignature())
```

Javascript (working)

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var jsSHA = require("jssha");
var forge = require("node-forge");

var returnSignature = () => {
    var password = "6b0d";
    var salt = "1234";
    var mod = "18482445774037006176143036388197818377224243341874299759393986316969168081293431967665057665354002144386679806241726680717167432197115393709044305367801562368377199313542622242088334493968227031303600659164182705200363370843349892071172286671217348220799611979367426886573857836700695154474387375045676161964264719840020610569587332497543980147743876907161648026576356758480646523434992364261325929823041766729482733300160147897964050534385377467240755626731087578114754411412866113305365456719741211653254865891742861999731525476635260033457850071277557432915055294927970289560714643822194080384022366782758886009197";
    var exp = "65537";

    var sha_1 = CryptoJS.SHA1(password);
    var SHA3_512_password_salted = new jsSHA("SHA3-512", "HEX");
    SHA3_512_password_salted.update(sha_1 + salt);

    var BigInteger = forge.jsbn.BigInteger;
    var n = new BigInteger(mod);
    var e = new BigInteger(exp);
    
    var publicKey = forge.pki.setRsaPublicKey(n, e);
    var encrypted = publicKey.encrypt(SHA3_512_password_salted.getHash("BYTES"), 'RSA-OAEP', {
        md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
        mgf1: {
            md: forge.md.sha1.create()
        }
    });

    return forge.util.bytesToHex(encrypted);
}

console.log(returnSignature())
```

The outputs are as follows:

python (too long):

```
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
```

Node (working):

```
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
```

Comment: `int(mod, 16)` parses `mod` as a base-16 number, but your Javascript is treating it as a base-10 integer.

Comment: changed to int(mod, 10) now the string lengths are matching, but still not working for some reason.

Comment: *...but still not working for some reason...* is not a proper error description! Anyway: The JavaScript code uses SHA256 as OAEP digest and SHA1 as MGF1 digest. In the Python code the default SHA1 is used for both digests, s. [`PKCS1_OAEP.new()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/oaep.html?highlight=mgf1#Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP.new). You have to specify the digests in the Python code, s. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65805979/9014097) how to do this.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous error line, my string is not accepted by a third party app. 

Looks like you are the winner, changed this line and my password is accepted:
encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(publicKey, Hash.SHA256, mgfunc = lambda x,y: PKCS1_OAEP.MGF1(x, y, Hash.SHA1))

Comment: @Topaco I owe you a  I would not have figured that out on my own